# MAX function not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table :

```
 fistname      | lastname     |  english 
--------------------------------------------- 
bob           | wilson       | 77  
jess          | farr         | 47
```

And this is my code in php :

```
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');    
mysql_select_db('education');
$highest= mysql_query("SELECT firstname, lastname, max(english)FROM students");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($highest);
echo 'English Highscore:' ;
echo "\r\n" ;
echo $row[0];
echo '&nbsp';
echo $row[1];
```

It will display jess as the one with the high score and not bob:

Comment: You have no group by statement

Comment: i shouldn't need it if i only want to display the name 1 person with the high score

Comment: `i shouldn't need it if i only want to display the name 1 person with the high score`:: Sorry - you are misinformed about how aggregate functions work. Your solution should be simply: `SELECT firstname, lastname, english FROM students ORDER BY english DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: MySQL permits columns in the `SELECT` list which are not also in the `GROUP BY`, often producing indeterminate and incorrect results. That's what you have here.

Comment: Thanks , i was misinformed .  Lets say I wanted to work out the average of all the scores , would the query be SELECT firstname, lastname, english FROM students AVG english DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: Average of **ALL** scores : `SELECT AVG(english) FROM students`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$highest= mysql_query("SELECT firstname, lastname, english FROM students order by english DESC limit 1");
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use aggregate function you need to use `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, MAX(english)
FROM students
GROUP BY lastname, firstname
```

From [**documentation**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

> - If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, english
FROM students
ORDER BY english DESC
LIMIT 1
```